# High level API for creating 2D Shapes in Java

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I am seeking an API or program which I can use to create [Shapes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) **graphically** in Java (specifically **closed** shapes). A tool simalar to paint in windows, but without the colors and such. After the shapes are created, I will be using them as part of a simulation program, so I need to get access to the actual java Shape objects.

I *could* create my own tool using Java2D, but I am sure I would be wasting my time as there must be some useful tools out there. However, after a long time scowering google, I had no luck. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/874351/A-Simple-Java-Drawing-Tool.htm) an article describing how to do it accompanied with source code that you might be able to use.